# Can this block of code be made into a function or simplified in some way?

Tags: python, function, loops, methods, abstract-class

Let's say I have this process:

```
found = 0
print_header()
for file in files_to_check
    print("Checking file: {}".format(file), end="")
    with open(file) as f:
       line_counter = 0
       for line in f:
            line_counter += 1
            print("-- Checking line: {}".format(line_counter), end="")

            # MY CHECK:
            # Some complex code that either increments "found" or not

            print("done with line")
    print("done with file")
print("FOUND:", found)
print_footer()
```

And let's say I want to do this over and over.  That is, I have different "checks" to run.  Some of them are simple, some are complex.  But they all have the same basic structure: walk through each file (printing a line each time the file is opened or closed) and walking through each line (printing the line number as it goes along), do something on each line, then do some printing and stuff after each line before beginning the next iteration.

I'd like to be able to abstract out as much of this as possible into a function or method (i.e. the printing of filenames, line counters, opening and closing files, looping through each line) so that I can define a series of functions (or classes) that contains just the heart of my check.

In pseudo-code, I would think of it as a partially-defined method, where the "checking" code in the middle would be left blank.  I could then instantiate this class as many times as I need, and just plug some custom code into the middle of the check() method for each instance.

Is such a construct possible in Python?  I looked into Abstract Base Classes, which seemed helpful, but didn't seem to include anything quite like I was looking for.

**EDIT:**

The difficulty in abstracting out this code (as I see it) is that it is operating on a series of files (`with open(file) as f`) and then looping over lines.  The part labeled `# MY CHECK` in example above is where many different, various things need to happen.  To make up some simple examples, let's say I want to go through each line of each file and:

1. Increment a counter if this line contains the word "foobar"
2. Print the value of  if the line contains the syntax "Hello, "
3. Print "LAMP" if the word "python" is in this line, and we have already seen the word "Apache" earlier in the file.
4. ...
5. ...

However, I do not want to run **all** of these checks on all files.  I may want to run #1 and #3.  Tomorrow, for a different business need, I may want to run #1, #4 and #23.  Therefore I need to have each "check" as its own function, or its own method.

What I'm trying to do is not have to duplicate the infrastructure that surrounds each check (setting up the files, opening them, printing headers and footers, etc.)

Comment: yes you can put it into a function....have you tried, what problem are you facing? what exactly is the complex code?

Comment: Every level of abstraction should be put in a different function.

Comment: I'm not sure how abstract base classes could help you here, or even classes. Your code seems pretty appropriately a function. Perhaps you are not aware, but functions are first-class objects in Python, and can be passed as arguments to a function, or returned from a function.

Comment: you could have this whole code as a function that receives as input the check function

    def check_in_files(checker):
        # your code
        # MY CHECK:
        found += 1 if checker(line) else 0
        # rest of the code
    def check1(line): 
        #some code

and you could call it ```check_in_files(check1)```

Comment: The question has been edited to explain the "checking" process further.

Comment: if it works, perhaps softwarenegineering or codereview would be better suited than SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use functions as parameters:

```
def file_checker(files_to_check, checker):
    found = 0
    print_header()
    for file in files_to_check:
        print("Checking file: {}".format(file), end="")
        with open(file) as f:
            for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
                print("-- Checking line: {}".format(num), end="")
                if checker(line):
                    found += 1
                print("done with line")
        print("done with file")
    print("FOUND:", found)
    print_footer()
    return found
```

or a generator:

```
def multi_file_line_iterator(files_to_check):
    print_header()
    for file in files_to_check:
        print("Checking file: {}".format(file), end="")
        with open(file) as f:
            for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
                print("-- Checking line: {}".format(num), end="")
                yield line
                print("done with line")
        print("done with file")
    print("FOUND:", found)
    print_footer()
    return found

found = 0
for line in multi_file_line_iterator(files_to_check):
    found += checker(line)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Functions are first-class objects in Python.
Since every checker basically only needs one argument (the line to check), you can use a checker function as a parameter of your looping function.

```
def test(filename, function):
    with open(filename) as foo:
        for line in foo:
            rv = function(line)
            print(function.__name__, 'returned:', rv)
```

Comment: Ah!  That is helpful - thank you.